# How do I select datediff between a date and time column and a date column from two different tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

So I have these two data tables, users and logins. There is a `registration_date` column for users and a `last_login` for logins. I am trying to find the average difference between the two columns from the two tables. What I believe to be the problem is that the `registration_date` is just date while the `last_login` is both date and time.

I first tried:

```
select avg(datediff(u.registration_date, l.last_login)) as avg_acttime from logins l 

left join users u on l.userid = u.id and type like '%new%';
```

My result was `null`.

So I then tried to convert the date and time `last_login` column to just date.

```
select avg(datediff((DATE_FORMAT(u.registration_date,'%d-%m-%y')), (DATE_FORMAT(l.last_login,'%d-%m-%y')))) as avg_acttime from logins l 

left join users u on l.userid = u.id and type like '%new%';
```

The result was again `null`. I need some serious help getting the difference in days between this date column from one table and a date and time column from another table.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  First, I think you intend for `users` to be the first table.  Then, you don't need a `left join`, because `avg()` ignores `NULL` values anyway.  So a `join` is sufficient:

```
select avg(datediff(u.registration_date, l.last_login)) as avg_acttime
from users u join
     logins l     
     on l.userid = u.id and type like '%new%';
```

You would get `NULL` values either because there are no rows generated by the `from` clause or all the rows have a `NULL` value for one of the columns.  More specifically, I can think of the following possibilities:

- `logins` or `users` has no rows.
- No rows match the `on` conditions.
- At least one of `u.registration_date` and `l.last_login` are always `NULL` for each login.

Having a `datetime` and `date` should not result in `NULL` values.

Of these, my guess is that no rows match the `on` condition.  The `type` comparison is the most likely cause of failure.  Without sample data, it is hard to say more.

Comment: right but the only thing that's weird is that when I do

Comment: select avg(datediff(l.last_login, u.datesent)) as "avg_signupdate-datesent_hrs" from letters l
 left join users u on l.userid = u.id and type like '%new%';

Comment: it comes out correctly so the on conditions seem to work fine. This leads me to believe it has something to do with the date and time being used with the date column. idk tho

Answer (score 0):

Your date format `%d-%m-%y` will yield very strange results, if any at all.
Change `%d-%m-%y` to

```
%Y-%m-%d
```

Mind the capital `Y`, or else mysql will format the date with 2 digits for year, what he will then confuse with the day.